# JLabel won't show the proper value of Getter

Tags: java

In my project, my problem is that the JLabel won't show the incremented value from the getter. It should be adding up everytime I choose the correct radiobutton.

This is the first JFrame

```
public class DifEasy extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

//        jPanel1.setVisible(false);
        if (q1a1.isSelected()){
            ScoreStorage mehh = new ScoreStorage();
            mehh.setRawscore(mehh.getRawscore()+1);

        }
        this.setVisible(false);
        new DifEasy1().setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is the 2nd JFrame

```
public class DifEasy1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (q1a1.isSelected()){
            ScoreStorage mehh = new ScoreStorage();          
            mehh.setRawscore(mehh.getRawscore()+1);

        }
        this.setVisible(false);
        new DifEasy2().setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is the 3rd JFrame

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (q1a1.isSelected()){
            ScoreStorage mehh = new ScoreStorage();          
            mehh.setRawscore(mehh.getRawscore()+1);
            jLabel1.setText(String.valueOf(mehh.getRawscore()));
        }
    }
```

btw I just put a JLabel there for testing. After clicking the JButton (Given that I choosed the q1a1 radiobutton), the JLabel should change into 3, but it shows up only 0.

Getters and Setters class

```
public class ScoreStorage {

    private int Rawscore = 0;

    public void setRawscore(int rawscore){
        this.Rawscore = Rawscore;
    }

    public int getRawscore(){
        return Rawscore;
    }

    public synchronized void increment(){
        setRawscore(Rawscore);
    }

    public int reset(){
        Rawscore = 0;
        return Rawscore;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a typo in ScoreStorage.setRawscore, you are assigning this.Rawscore = Raswcore instead of this.Rawscore = rawscore. It may be causing your problem. Member Rawscore is always 0.

Comment: Each time you select an option, you are creating a brand new instance of `ScoreStorage`, which is initialised to `0`, you then add `1` to it ... but as has been pointed out ... you're not assigning the correct value - so it's always `0`

Comment: I'd discourage multiple frames like this, and instead encourage using a `CardLayout`, however, having said that, a single instance of `ScoreStorage` should be passed to each class which needs it

Comment: @MadProgrammer I changed the this.Rawscore but still it gives a value of 1. :(
And how can I declare a single instance of ScoreStorage to every class?

Comment: Where is your main class? What about instantiating ScoreStorage there and passing a reference on creating your JFrames? You can implement a method setScoreStorage or create a constructor that accepts that argument in your JFrames.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand it very well but I get the idea. I don't have a main class. It started from a main menu jframe and it connects to those other jframes via action listener. Well, I instantiate the ScoreStorage in one class as public, but I don't know how to call it in other class. Can you give me an example? @RubioRic

Comment: @Katsueki [Passing information to a method or a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*(Based on the comments from [RubioRic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2553194/rubioric) and [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer))*</sub>

The code has two problems:

1. the Setter in `ScoreStorage` doesn't work:

> You've got a typo in ScoreStorage.setRawscore, you are assigning `this.Rawscore = Raswcore` instead of `this.Rawscore = rawscore` therefore the value of `Rawscore` is always 0.

(also note that `ScoreStorage.increment()` probably doesn't do what it should since it only reassign the value.)

2. You create multiply `ScoreStorage` objects.

> Each time you select an option, you are creating a brand new instance of `ScoreStorage`, which is initialised to `0`.
>
> You can implement a method `setScoreStorage` or create a constructor that accepts that argument in your JFrames.

---

Here is a short example how to pass one `ScoreStorage` between the different JFrame with a constructor

```
public class DifEasy extends JFrame {
    private ScoreStorage scoreStorage;

    public DifEasy(ScoreStorage scoreStorage) {
        this.scoreStorage = scoreStorage;
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if (q1a1.isSelected()){
            scoreStorage.setRawscore(scoreStorage.getRawscore()+1);
        }
        this.setVisible(false);
        new DifEasy1(scoreStorage).setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the mention :-)